# Linq Lambda statement to find elements from one list of complex objects that match elements from another list of complex objects

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

Consider the following:

Object A has properties:

```
Name
Location
```

Object B has properties:

```
Nickname
Name
Location
City
State
```

I have a `List<ObjectA>` and `List<ObjectB>`

I'm trying to work out a linq statement that will return all Objects from `List<ObjectB>` that have a `Name` and a `Location` that Exist in `List<ObjectA>`
Everything I have found is based on simple objects or lists of identical objects, not lists of unique objects that have similar properties.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Read about the [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) statement and the corresponding [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549267(v=vs.100).aspx) method.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually this is simply a join of these two tables.

```
var query = listB.GroupJoin(listA,
    b => new{ b.Name, b.Location},
    a => new{ a.Name, a.Location},
    (b,matchingAs) => b);
```

Comment: @eBot Then you must be passing in a null value.  Don't do that; pass in a non-null value.  You should never have null collections, you should only ever possibly have empty collections.

Comment: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupJoin<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TOuter>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>, System.Func<TOuter,TKey>, System.Func<TInner,TKey>, System.Func<TOuter,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @eBot Then the types (or names) of your properties must be different.  You'll need to perform whatever conversions you need to do to make them entirely equivalent.

Comment: I resolved, I explicitly defined the types of my Output and Input Lists and then used object for the anonymous types

Comment: @eBot Then it'll compile and fail to work properly.  You're hiding the problem instead of fixing it.

Comment: the types for name and location are equivalent they are both strings in each object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56373/discussion-between-ebot-and-servy).

Answer (score 1):

```
listB.Where(x => listA.Any(a => a.Name == x.Name && a.Location == x.Location));
```

Comment: could you explain how this works?

Comment: This is going to do a linear search through the list for every single object, which is going to scale quite a lot more poorly than a hash based solution.

Comment: @Servy Unfortunately im not familiar with hash based solutions, could you point me to some documentation on those?

Comment: @eBot I posted an answer with one 5 minutes ago...

Comment: @Servy What defines your posted answer as a "Hash based" solution

Comment: @eBot The way that `GroupJoin` is implemented.  It, internally, is going to use a far more efficient algorithm, specifically, it's going to use the hash codes of each key to find the appropriate matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can join lists of different types, and use an anonymous type to define "equality":

```
var query = 
    from b in listB
    join a in listA into As
    on new {b.Name, b.Location} equals new {a.Name, a.Location}
    select b;
```

Comment: If there are multiple matches for an object this will yield it multiple times; you should be using a `GroupJoin` rather than a `Join` to resolve that.

Comment: would this work for "Many" matches, lets say 1 element from listB would match many in list a

Comment: @eBot No, as per my previous comment, but it's a trivial alteration.

Comment: @eBot No, I've reversed the order and added a grouping to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: @DStanley You're still not using a group join.  (There is no `into`.)  And when you add grouping, you'll need to reverse the order of the lists so that `b` is first, else `b` wont' be in scope in the selector, and the `on` clause will need to be reversed accordingly.

Comment: @Servy - weird, I had done that but it didn't get saved. I blame SO - there's absolutely no chance that I didn't hit `Save Edits`. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ObjectA> listA = new List<ObjectA>();
List<ObjectB> listB = new List<ObjectB>();

List<ObjectB> commonList = listB.Where(b => listA.Any(a => b.Name == a.Name && a.Location == b.Location)).ToList();
```

That would give you all the objects in B that have a matching name and location in list A